# Laravel 5.3 : How to inject variables into "layout" page?

Tags: laravel-5.3

Laravel 5.3 : How to inject variables into "layout" page?

I tried "Service Injection" , like this:

```
@inject('siteInfo', 'App\Services\SiteInformation')
    <title>{{ $siteInfo->name }}</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{ $siteInfo->keywords }}"/>
    <meta name="description" content="{{ $siteInfo->description }}"/>
```

**SiteInformation.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\SiteInfo;


class SiteInformation
{

    public $siteInfo;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->siteInfo = SiteInfo::all();

    }
}
```

**error:**

```
Undefined property: App\Services\SiteInformation::$name (View: D:\wnmp\www\laravel-5-3-dev\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)
```

**Questions:**

1.How could I modify the code?
2.Are there any other ways to do it?

**Edit:**

And I tried   another way in  `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('layouts/app', function ($view) {
        $siteInfo=SiteInfo::all();
        dd($siteInfo);
        $view->with('siteName',$siteInfo->name)   // this is line 22
            ->with('siteKeywords',$siteInfo->keywords)
            ->with('siteDescription',$siteInfo->description);
    });
}
```

The error is the same:

```
ErrorException in AppServiceProvider.php line 22:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$name (View: D:\wnmp\www\laravel-5-3-dev\resources\views\pages\index.blade.php)
```

The location of line 22  has comment in AppServiceProvider.php.

The result of `dd($siteInfo);`:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed `$name` property does not exist. Try:

```
@inject('siteInfo', 'App\Services\SiteInformation')
<title>{{ $siteInfo->siteInfo->name }}</title>
```

or if it is an array:

```
<title>{{ $siteInfo->siteInfo['name'] }}</title>
```

#### Edit

Based in your print, try to get a single item instead a collection:

```
public function __construct() {

    $this->siteInfo = SiteInfo::first();

}
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
<title>{{ $siteInfo->siteInfo->name }}</title>
```

Comment: I can neither get the property value,I added the result of dd(),see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

`SiteInfo::all()` returns a collection of rows, here it has only one row.

So you could do:

```
$rows = SiteInfo::all();
$siteInfo = $rows->first();
```

But better, just use Eloquent's method:

```
$siteInfo = SiteInfo::first();
```